# shell pipe process repeat

Tags: bash, shell, sed, pipe

I want to do something like this:

```
~ cat dump.sh
command 1 | command 2 | command 1 | command 2 | ...(ten times) | command 1 | command2

~ ./dump.sh < demo.log
```

So how to modify `dump.sh` while I can specify exactly `n` times of `command 1` and `command 2` in pair to process demo.log?

Comment: Can you provide two simple commands what can  be applied n times in pair on a demo.log file? It's not easy to figure out, and hence, to help you.

Comment: Once you catch yourself repeating things like this it often means that there is a better way to do whatever you are doing.

Comment: @zezollo It's hard to imagine a scenario where this would be *actually* useful, but it's not hard to come up with a pair of filters which do ... something.  I used `sed "s/^/one /"` and `sed "s/^/two /"` for testing.

Comment: Brainteasers, just for fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive helper function, something like this:

```
loop () {
    case $1 in
      0) cat;;
      *) command 1 | command 2 | loop $(($1 - 1)) ;;
    esac
}
```

Invoke it like

```
loop 3 <demo.log
```