# How to filter defined patterns within multiple/separated lines

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

Here's my log's simple general specification:

- one request comes, logs `...[XXXHandler] comming time...`
- get lock and start transaction, logs `...[XXXHandler] [`*`UID`*`] start time...`
- business finished and return the lock, logs `...[XXXHandler] [`*`UID`*`] spend time...`

In practice, there's ton's of requests flush in with respective *UID*, and the three lines pattern cluttered within each other. Here's a part of it:

```
~ cat sample.log
[240] [DeleteAllLettersHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [DeleteAllLettersHandler] [13497] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [DeleteAllLettersHandler] [13497] spend time [1] dbs 1 dbu 1 | {}
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [1495] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [1495] spend time [1] dbs 1 dbu 0 | {}
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] [8941] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [GetResHarvestInfoHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [GetResHarvestInfoHandler] [1807] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [RCHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]     ## gotcha
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] [8941] spend time [10] dbs 27 dbu 2 | {}
[240] [GetResHarvestInfoHandler] [1807] spend time [5] dbs 15 dbu 4 | {}
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [18052] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [18052] spend time [1] dbs 1 dbu 0 | {}
[240] [GetResourceAmount] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [GetResourceAmount] [29063] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [GetResourceAmount] [29063] spend time [1] dbs 3 dbu 0 | {}
```

My requirement is to filter the log, remove the cluttered three lines patterns while I can see which handler is hanging (logs coming but no start time).

---

Here's my solution:

```
- cat process.sh

sed -r '
    $!N
    $!N
    $!N
    s/(([^\n]*\n)*)[^\n]*\[([^\n]*)\] coming time[^\n]*\n(([^\n]*\n)*)[^\n]*\[\3\] \[([^\n]*)\] start time[^\n]*\n(([^\n]*\n)*)[^\n]*\[\3\] \[\6\] spend time[^\n]*(.*)/\1\4\7\9/
    t print     
    P
    D

    :print
' |

grep -v '^ *$'
```

This can filter some patterns but not all of it, since the sed could process one pattern scattered in three or four (with the sed round adds may be more) lines.

```
~ ./process.sh < sample.log
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [1495] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [1495] spend time [1] dbs 1 dbu 0 | {}
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] [8941] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [RCHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]     ## gotcha
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] [8941] spend time [10] dbs 27 dbu 2 | {}
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [18052] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [StartBiddingAllianceBossAuctionHandler] [18052] spend time [1] dbs 1 dbu 0 | {}
```

Using the filtered logs as the SEED, filter it again and again, I can get the result I want:

```
~ ./process.sh < sample.log | ./process.sh
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] [8941] start time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]
[240] [RCHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]     ## gotcha
[240] [GetMazeMainInfoHandler] [8941] spend time [10] dbs 27 dbu 2 | {}

~ ./process.sh < sample.log | ./process.sh | ./process.sh
[240] [RCHandler] coming time [Fri Mar 18 05:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016]     ## gotcha
```

It seems like that I just have to filter a few more times to get the result eventually I need. So I asked one question: [shell pipe process repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002431/shell-pipe-process-repeat), 
@tripleee answer works great for me. Roughly after five times filter I can get the final result for every log.

---

But the time-consuming is too much, one 10K lines log usually cost 10 minutes to be filtered this way.

So my question is, can you figure out a better way to do this? or how to improve my way to let it run faster.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Counting of coming time and start time records is not enough for you?

Comment: @user3132194 I have to locate which handler is hanging there.

Comment: If the handler that's hung never starts again, you can simplify the task by getting the *last occurence* of each handler and check if it contains ```coming time```.

Comment: @Hedley Yan I mean you can count occurrences of coming and start record by handler. If they differs for a long time - then something went wrong with this handler. If it is some kind of monitoring task, then you can check it online by piping `tail -f` to your script, it should ease performance problem.

Comment: @user3132194 get your point, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think bash is competent for your question.

I would like to recommend you to try perl. Parsing log and saving [Handler Name, question, start,finish] quadruple into a hash table, then you can scan the hash table to find which handler is hanging. This is more extensible solution, IMHO.

Comment: Thx for your advice! I don't use perl or other advance language for two reasons:

1. There's other log info cluttered in the three lines patterns, which is helpful to me, I have to remain them.
2. one definite [XXHandler] [UID] ... may occur multiple times, and the Handler and UID combinations are exploded. if I use hash to help me filter the pattern, I doubt the efficiency as well. 

Thx anyway, also I want to see is there another delicate solution.

Comment: @HedleyYan, More complicated your task are, more reasonably you should use advance language.